# Using JERSEY and JACKSON to parse a POST request with unknown structure

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm in a current situations in which I have a REST endpoint that accepts POST of incoming JSON messages.

The thing is that I don't think I can specify the POJO object so Jackson can marshall the JSON into the POJO object. Reason for this is that I don't have control of what comes to that endpoint, and number of fields and type can change over time, thus, defining a POJO before hand seems not an option.

So I guess the question is....can I simply tell Jackson to don't do any marshalling and give the String of the response? I can deal with that later with JSONObject-JSONArray or Gson maybe. Say I'd have a method like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/callback")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response facebookUpdate(String json) {
    //Do something with the json response...
}
```

If this is not feasible with Jersey-JAX...any other alternatives?

Thanks!
Alejandro

Comment: It is feasible. However, instead of handling this explicitly, I'd implement a custom parameter class. Jersey is not very picky, you can just have an object of literally any class that provides a `valueOf(String)` method, a constructor taking a `String` as a parameter or a `fromString(String)` method. Sounds like a nice place to encapsulate the parsing.

Comment: Good point, I'll try that Tom, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to simply not inject the json into the method and use the request object instead:

```
public Response facebookUpdate(@Context request) {
    try(InputStream is=request.getEntityInputStream()) {
       ...
    }
}
```

From the request you can then get an inputstream for the request and parse it whichever way you like.

For parsing I can recommend my own [jsonj](https://github.com/jillesvangurp/jsonj) library, which was written specifically to support open ended scenarios like you describe and uses jackson to deserialize into heavily customised implementations of java.util.Map and java.util.List. Gson is also a very solid choice.

If you want to do this application wide, you can instead write your own @Provider and do the same there. This is how I use my library currently actually.

Comment: Thanks Jilles, I'll take a look at your library. This is a valid response so it goes for you. As a side note, I tried passing a simple String to the method and it works too, so I can do the parsing directly too...just in case any other runs into this :)

Comment: yes, I guess that depends what types the jackson provider is configured to handle. Still, not buffering things as a String before you parse them is always nice.